# why the merge can not work in the for-loop?

Tags: r

I can merge data in this way:

```
total<-rare8000
total<-merge(total,rare9000,by="sampleID")
total<-merge(total,rare10000,by="sampleID")
total<-merge(total,rare11000,by="sampleID")
total<-merge(total,rare12000,by="sampleID")
```

I got the results I want.

but I can not merge in this way:

```
total<-rare8000
for(i in seq(9000,12000,by=1000)) {
    temp<-paste0("rare",i)
    total<-merge(total,temp,by="sampleID")
}
```

As it ends with the following error:

> Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely 
>   valid column

What is the problem? Can anyone tell me the difference between the two pieces of codes above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop you do

```
  temp <- paste0("rare",i)
```

That creates a string object named `temp` with value "rare9000". That is not equivalent to the object with the name `rare9000` (which presumably is a data.frame or matrix)

You could try:

```
  temp <- eval(parse(text=paste0("rare",i)))
```

Because:

```
x <- 2
'x'
# [1] "x"
eval(parse(text='x'))
# [1] 2
```

Having objects like `rare9000`, `rare10000` etc is a sign of poor programming. You should probably create a list such that you do not need to call these by name in the first place. To get better help you should provide a more complete example.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I just find out "assign" will return the same result as "eval".